# Using case and group by in select statement not working

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case

I'm using a case and group by in a select statement and I would like for the case field name (item number) to not be apart of the group by clause statement. I've calculated the invoice weight as well as the shipping weight. This is what I have thus far. The issue is when the calculation is done with the case and group by on the item number, providing multiple rows however, I would like only one row.

```
    SELECT TOP 10 S.SOPNUMBE, CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(S.CUSTNAME)) ,' ' ,(RTRIM(LTRIM(S.[ADDRESS1]))) ,' ' ,(RTRIM(LTRIM(S.[ADDRESS3]))))AS CUSTNAME,

            S.[CSTPONBR],S.DOCDATE, CAST(round(Sum(QUANTITY),2) as numeric(12,0))TotalOnInvoice,  (CASE 

            WHEN I.ITEMNMBR = 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-KILOM-FORN'

            THEN  CAST(cast(Sum(QUANTITY * 30 ) as decimal(10,0))as float) 

            WHEN I.ITEMNMBR = 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-20.0K-FORN'

            THEN  CAST(cast(Sum(QUANTITY * 20 ) as decimal(10,2))as float)                     

            WHEN I.ITEMNMBR = 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-2.25K-FORN'

            THEN  CAST(cast(Sum(QUANTITY * 2.25 ) as decimal(10,2))as float)

            ELSE CAST(cast(Sum([ITEMSHWT] * Quantity) as decimal(10,0))as float)/100 

            END) AS TotalShippingWeight

            FROM [TWCL].[dbo].[SOP30200] S inner JOIN twcl.dbo.SOP30300 P ON S.SOPNUMBE=P.SOPNUMBE inner join [TWCL].[dbo].[IV00101] I on 

            P.ITEMNMBR= I.ITEMNMBR WHERE CSTPONBR='1343231 ' 

            GROUP BY S.SOPNUMBE, S.CUSTNAME, S.[CSTPONBR], S.DOCDATE, S.[ADDRESS3], S.ADDRESS1,I.ITEMNMBR
```

This is the outcome I'm receiving now

[image]

This is the outcome I would like to receive.

[image]

New Query

```
    SELECT TOP 10 S.SOPNUMBE, CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(S.CUSTNAME)) ,' ' ,(RTRIM(LTRIM(S.[ADDRESS1]))) ,' ' ,(RTRIM(LTRIM(S.[ADDRESS3]))))AS CUSTNAME,

            S.[CSTPONBR],S.DOCDATE, CAST(round(Sum(QUANTITY),2) as numeric(12,0))TotalOnInvoice, SUM (CASE 

            WHEN I.ITEMNMBR = 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-KILOM-FORN'

            THEN  CAST(cast(Sum(QUANTITY * 30 ) as decimal(10,0))as float) 

            WHEN I.ITEMNMBR = 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-20.0K-FORN'

            THEN  CAST(cast(Sum(QUANTITY * 20 ) as decimal(10,2))as float)                     

            WHEN I.ITEMNMBR = 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-2.25K-FORN'

            THEN  CAST(cast(Sum(QUANTITY * 2.25 ) as decimal(10,2))as float)

            ELSE CAST(cast(Sum([ITEMSHWT] * Quantity) as decimal(10,0))as float)/100 

            END) AS TotalShippingWeight

            FROM [TWCL].[dbo].[SOP30200] S inner JOIN twcl.dbo.SOP30300 P ON S.SOPNUMBE=P.SOPNUMBE inner join [TWCL].[dbo].[IV00101] I on 

            P.ITEMNMBR= I.ITEMNMBR WHERE CSTPONBR='1343231 ' 

            GROUP BY S.SOPNUMBE, S.CUSTNAME, S.[CSTPONBR], S.DOCDATE, S.[ADDRESS3], S.ADDRESS1,I.ITEMNMBR
```

Error message:Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Try to come up with a minimal example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I've added pictures and more info on the issue

Comment: You need a sum on your "case" if you want it to be the sum in your resultset

Comment: When I sum the case, it gives this error message Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Welcome to **Database Administrators**. Please, check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to better understand what Laurenz Albe asked for. That shall help us to better help you ;)

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher, I tried the sum and I'm getting an error

Comment: show us your new query and the error you got please

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher, I've added the new query and error

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher, I'm not understanding what i'm doing incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this demo code :

```
125342', 'Some Fake Name', 1343632, GETDATE(), 3, 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-20.0K-FORN'),('INV000125342', 'Some Fake Name', 1343632, GETDATE(), 11, 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-2.25K-FORN'),
('INV000125342', 'Some Fake Name', 1343632, GETDATE(), 2, 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-2.25K-FORN'),('INV000125342', 'Some Fake Name', 1343632, GETDATE(), 7, 'FG-PD-TJ-PQ-2.25K-FORN'),
('INV000125342', 'Some Fake Name', 1343632, GETDATE(), 2, 'Other'),('INV000125342', 'Some Fake Name', 1343632, GETDATE(), 3, 'Other')


select SOPNUMBE, CUSTNAME, CUSTNBR, DOCDATE,
SUM(QUANTITY) "TotalOnInvoce", 
sum(Case when ITEMNBR='FG-PD-TJ-PQ-KILOM-FORN' then QUANTITY*30
when ITEMNBR='FG-PD-TJ-PQ-20.0K-FORN' then QUANTITY*20
when ITEMNBR='FG-PD-TJ-PQ-2.25K-FORN' then QUANTITY *2.5
end) as "TotalShippingWeight"
from #demo
group by SOPNUMBE, CUSTNAME, CUSTNBR, DOCDATE

drop table #demo
```

I hope this will help you.